# Webstorm Autocomplete with Views folder

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm

My project uses server rendering to serve up **.html** files from the **/views** folder, and static asset folders such as /styles and /scripts from the **app** folder.

In my index.html I link to the stylesheet in the /styles folder, but the url isn't actually valid until the express server mounts the folders, so Webstorms autocomplete doesn't recognize the stylesheet.

Is there anyway to tell webstorm where the stylesheet actually is?

Answer (score 2):

try marking your /styles folder as a resource root (right-click the folder, Mark directory as -> Resource root)

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't change anything for me.

Comment: what is your actual file structure, and what does your URL in index.html look like?